# MIPS registers that hold memory addresses

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm confused on how MIPS general purpose registers can hold a memory address and how you can "deference" that address. For example, say register R1 holds the memory address of the starting location of an array. How would I use R1 to get the contents of the first element in the array? For simplicity sake, let's say the starting address of our array is 1 so R1 will hold the memory address of 1. What set of instructions do I use to get the first element in register R2? LW sounds like a good start but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Yes, `lw` and friends. Read an instruction set reference.

Comment: I did thank you. What I'm confused on is how LW can use what the register's holding to load a word from memory OR use the register itself as an address like Register indirect addressing. For example, say we just started up our machine and all our registers hold the value zero. If I have two instructions like, lw r1, 0(r2) and lw r3,0(r4). Does r2 and r4 correspond to the same memory location?

Comment: Yes, all registers behave the same for this, so with the same value in R2 and R4, both of those *addressing modes* (google that) give the same address.  (And the address is the integer value in the register.)  This is assembly language, everything is just bits and bytes, with no data type stuff done for you.